# Force Vuetify VTextField to update value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a custom VTextField that only accepts numbers and also formats the number. It should update the VTextField value to the filtered and formatted value, but it won't do as expected.

I think the reason is that the `display_value` stays the same when the user enters non-numeric characters and it won't update/re-render component. Is there anyway that I can correctly make this work? Thanks.

Nuxt Version: 2.14

Vuetify Version: 2

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    :value="display_value"
    @input="input($event)"
  >
  </v-text-field>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      display_value: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    input(value) {
      let filtered = this.onlyNumbers(value);
      this.$emit('input', filtered);
      this.display_value = Number(filtered).toLocaleString();
      console.log('input=', value);
      console.log('display_value=', this.display_value);
    },
    onlyNumbers(value) {
      value = String(value);
      return value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of hack.

```js
<template>
  <v-text-field
    ref="inputRef"
    :value="display_value"
    @input="input($event)"
  >
  </v-text-field>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      display_value: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    input(value) {
      let filtered = this.onlyNumbers(value);
      this.$emit('input', filtered);
      this.display_value = Number(filtered).toLocaleString();
      console.log('input=', value);
      console.log('display_value=', this.display_value);
      this.$refs.inputRef.lazyValue = this.display_value;
    },
    onlyNumbers(value) {
      value = String(value);
      return value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is demo: https://codepen.io/init-qy/pen/bGOzLMQ